# Your app is using the Unity SDK which collects but may not be limited to Android ID and Advertising ID identifiers

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, playback

How can I solve this issue? app is rejected by playstore due to this reason.
Your app is using the Unity SDK which collects but may not be limited to Android ID and Advertising ID identifiers. Persistent device identifiers may not be linked to other personal and sensitive user data or resettable device identifiers.
You may consider moving to another SDK; removing this SDK; or if available from your SDK provider, upgrading to a policy-compliant version of this SDK that does not include the violating code.

According to the information provided by your SDK provider, you may consider upgrading to 4.0.1. Please consult the SDK provider for further information.

Comment: Hello - did you find a solution for this? I am having the same problem and App rejection.

Answer (score 1):

If your game doesn't have any advertisements, consider removing the "Advertisement" package. On the other hand, if your game contains ads, it's advisable to upgrade the "Advertisement" package to the latest version.